# Profile returns null while using Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook

The profile.getProfile() returns null while running below code.
I am using proper hashkey, proper app ID.
I am stopping the profile and access tracer in onDestory() method
I am not using any facebook app
Any idea to fix this.

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstane)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstane);
            // Add code to print out the key hash

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken1) {

                }
            };
            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {

                }
            };
            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
        }


     private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mcallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Uri link = profile.getProfilePictureUri(20, 20);
                Log.d("Message",link.toString());
                display(profile);
            }
        };


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

void facebookLogin()
    {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
        LoginButton login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button_facebook);
        login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, mcallBackFacebook);
    }
```

Comment: have you given the permissions before getting facebook details ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. In your Activity

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

       callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


       LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
           new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                   GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                           loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                           new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                               @Override
                               public void onCompleted(
                                   JSONObject object,
                                   GraphResponse response) {
                                   // Call service for check facebook auth from server
                                   try {
                                       mFBID = encodeToBase64("" + object.get("email"));
                                       System.out.println("Your facebook is is-----" + mFBID);
                                       //YOUR CODE
                                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                               }
                           });

                   //its will return id, name and email
                   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                   parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                   request.setParameters(parameters);
                   request.executeAsync();

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancel() {
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });


       setContentView(R.layout.XML);

   }
   ```
2. call in the onClick event of the FB button:

   ```
   LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(_activity, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
   ```
3. onActivityResult()

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
   ```
4. Get hashKey and create key and in the manifest file register FacebookActivity.

Try it.. working fine here

Comment: I have followed your steps but its still not working .. Why the onSuccess is repeated two times ...first time : declaring mCallback in my code and second one is in onCreate() of your code. Also, i am not getting where exactly i need to place read permissions